# Thymleaf: Adding attribute in div tag

Tags: thymeleaf

I need to add an attribute in with in div tag in thymleaf as follows

```
<div class="mp_snippet_address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

the problem is i could not define the itemscope in div tag

Comment: What is you problem exactly? What do you mean by 'i could not define the itemscope' ?

Comment: The `itemscope` tag attribute does not have a value, which is not valid in XHTML. However, in HTML5 this is valid. What is your template mode?

Answer (score 2):

The standard HTML parser in Thymeleaf is a very strict XML parser.  You can switch to the less-strict LEGACYHTML5 template mode (then include the nekoHTML 1.9.15+ as a dependency), which allows for 'boolean attributes', but the output may be slightly different than the input templates as I think it performs some kind of tag balancing to massage HTML5 into being well-formed XML.

Support for HTML as per the HTML spec is on the cards for Thymeleaf 3.0, but that version is still a very very very long way away.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the th:attr attribute like this:

```
<div class="mp_snippet_address" th:attr="itemscope=true" th:attr-itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

This will add the itemscope attribute with the value of true and the itemtype attribute with the value of http://schema.org/LocalBusiness in the div tag.